# How much data transferred per user via SSH over time period

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, bandwidth, traffic-shaping

I have an Ubuntu server with approximately 20 users who primarily use it for SSH tunneling.

I would like to know if there is any way to determine the amount of data transferred by each user over a specific time period, such as the past week or month.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good question i found a view answers:

1. [How to measure bandwidth of SSH connection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/670549/how-to-measure-bandwidth-of-ssh-connection)

   > ```
   > iftop -i "$iface" -nPf "tcp and port $sport and port $dport"
   > ```
   >
   > Where `$iface` is the interface the packets for the ssh connection would be sent/received on, and `$sport/$dport` the source and the destination TCP ports. You could refine the filter further by also specifying the source and destination IP addresses.
2. [How much data does SSH typically use?](https://superuser.com/questions/624720/how-much-data-does-ssh-typically-use)

   > You should run `tcpdump -ni eth0 -w dump port 22` to capture all your packets, then `tcpdump -nX -r dump` to view them.
3. [Is there any way to track SSH traffic (bandwidth usage) per user basis?](https://serverfault.com/questions/394334/is-there-any-way-to-track-ssh-traffic-bandwidth-usage-per-user-basis)

   > I would use iptables owner module (perhaps together with other
   > quota/reporting modules).
   >
   > ```
   > iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m owner --uid someuser -j ACCEPT
   > ```
   >
   > And then see the output from `iptables -vL` to see the amount of
   > packets/bytes passed through this rule, or parse the iptables
   > statistics with some analyzer.

**To track data over a specific time period, you may need to periodically reset the statistics and collect the data at regular intervals, such as weekly or monthly.**

Redirect the output of `iptables -vL` to a file for analysis.

```
iptables -vL > ssh_traffic.txt
```

Reset the statistics:

`iptables -Z` reset the statistics for the `iptables` rule that tracks SSH traffic.

[iptables(8) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables)

You can also write a `bash script` and run it with `cron` or `anacron`, to execute the script automatically at the desired intervals to collect and analyze the traffic.

- [cron(8) — Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html)
- [anacron(8) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/anacron)
- [crontab(5) — Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html)

**There is another option** using `iptables`, `conntrack` and `connmark` together, but you'll have to take a look yourself.

- [How to catch conntrack markers correctly?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420098/how-to-catch-conntrack-markers-correctly)
- [CONNMARK on rewritten packets](https://superuser.com/questions/669804/connmark-on-rewritten-packets)
- [CONNTRACK(8)](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/conntrack/conntrack.8.en.html)
- [CONNMARK target](https://book.huihoo.com/iptables-tutorial/x9125.htm)
- [Iptables / What is the difference between connmark and mark?](https://serverfault.com/questions/407411/iptables-what-is-the-difference-between-connmark-and-mark)